# How to send request with different languages letters

Tags: jmeter

I want to send request. In body should be json with "Name": "úůýžáčďéěíňóřšťåæéøéäåö€ûüÿ€àâæçéèêëïîôœ»äöß€θωερτψυιοπασφγηςλάέåæâéèêźżó不八百北不大岛的弟地东都对多" 
By Postman I can send such kind of request but in JMeter I got the message {"message":"Object is null or can't be parsed\r\nParameter name: dto"}. Does anybody has idea how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Post your code how to send request ?

Comment: In body {"Id": null, "Name": "úůýžáčďéěíňóřšťåæéøéäåö€ûüÿ€àâæçéèêëïîôœ»äöß€θωερτψυιοπασφγηςλάέåæâéèêźżó不八百北不大岛的弟地东都对多", .....}

In path /api/something

Comment: what is this id = null ?

Comment: it is just the example  of POST request which should create something new with new ID

Comment: I think its not request language problem.

Comment: Yes. The problem is in JMeter cofiguration. That's why I asked for help

Answer (score 0):

HTTPClient3.1 in Implementation field on HTTP Request should be